# Get width/frame of entire UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a method where I have a (rendered) UITableViewCell*. I would like to know the width/frame of the entire cell.

`cell.frame` doesn't seem to work - it gives me the frame of a random cell. The closest I got is `cell.contentView.frame` but it doesn't include the area covered by the `accessoryView` (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7). `cell.contentView.superview.frame` doesn't work either - it gives me a frame at some arbitrary location just like `cell.frame` does.

`cell.contentView.width` + `cell.accessoryView.width` works except in cases where the accessory view is `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`

Any ideas how I can get the entire frame/width of the `UITableViewCell` in all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by default, a cell will use 100% of the width of the UITableView so a UITableView's width is equivalent to a cell's width and because you would likely have set your table cell height using:

```
[UITableView setRowHeight:tableCellHeight];
```

Where tableCellHeight is a number of your choice and UITableView is the name of your UITableView not the UITableView class itself.

Then you would have both the width and height of a table cell, or did I misinterpret your question?

Answer (score 12):

Try this,

```
NSLog(@"Cell Width = %f",cell.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"Cell Height = %f",cell.frame.size.height);
```

It will show the current cell Width and Height.

Comment: Yes, width/height are accurate. However, cell.offset is all wonky - any idea why?

Comment: Try this for Offset..  cell.frame.x, cell.frame.y

Comment: Try this `cell.frame.origin.x` , `cell.frame.origin.y`.

Answer (score 4):

This code gives you the frame of the particular cell selected by indexPath:

```
 // Get the cell rect and adjust it to consider scroll offset
    CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cellRect = CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x - tableView.contentOffset.x, cellRect.origin.y - tableView.contentOffset.y, cellRect.size.width, cellRect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 2):

`cell.frame` will always give you the frame of the cell you're messaging.

And even if it *did* return a random cell, you should still be able to use the width of the frame, because all the cells have the same width.

Comment: Yea, I can use the width but not the frame. Any clue why it won't return the frame of the current cell? The y-offset is way off. cell.contentView.frame seems to be correct though (except for the width issue)

Comment: The `frame` method must return the frame of the object that is being messaged, in this case the cell. If it returns a frame for another object, you should file a bug with Apple (or double check your code to make sure the frame is actually wrong).